# python requests not working with google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch a page using python requests with this code in `views.py`:

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://www.23andme.com/")
```

I get the error `Exceeded 30 redirects.` My app is a Google App Engine Django app. I've gotten this code to work in the python console and a django server on pythonanywhere.com, but for some reason it isn't working on google app engine. What could be causing this? Thanks

Edit: It seems like there is another issue with the Requests module in my app. I have this code to add an email to a mailchimp list:

```
m = mailchimp.Mailchimp(MAILCHIMP_API_KEY)
list_response = m.lists.list()
```

but if fails with the error `HTTPS/SSL is required`

Comment: A `requests` session saves cookies too, the site is redirecting you for a different reason.

Comment: Could it be the user agent? How can I make requests simulate a browser?

Comment: Usually it's one or more of the headers, yes. Add a `headers=..` dictionary and start copying headers your browser sends, see what makes it work.

Comment: I discovered it works while in the python console but not in views.py in django

Comment: This code works for me:

    ``def index(request):
         import requests
         s = requests.Session()
         r = s.get("https://www.23andme.com/")
         return HttpResponse(r.text)``

When I access the function (Django 1.6.0, python 2.7.3, local server), the page for www.23andme.com is rendered.

Comment: I was also able to get it to work on a pythonanywhere.com django server but it isn't working on my google apps engine django app. Does GAE have something to do with it?

Comment: Could be; I've not had problems with `requests` on GAE before though.

Comment: What python version are you using? (also, what happens if you try to do a request to a non `https` url?)

Comment: works with request library 2.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1905) discussion, the issue is with netrc on Google App Engine. I was able to work around the problem by using an older version of Requests ([1.2.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/1.2.3) in my case, but others may work too.)

Edit: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605328/python-requests-on-google-app-engine-not-working-for-https?rq=1) answer, Requests 2.1.0 should work as well.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605328/python-requests-on-google-app-engine-not-working-for-https?rq=1) as well

Answer (score 5):

Try installing [urllib3](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3) (and other stuff, see below).

See, historically there were tons of issues for requests with google app engine (and see issue [#498](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/498)). Those were mostly resolved with urllib3 support for GAE that came with [v1.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urllib3/#changes). It came out a long time ago (the current release is 1.7), so its probably not the issue, however when you initially install requests, it includes `urllib3` in a folder called `packages` and maybe it doesn't include the entirey of it.

I also tried searching the source code for `requests` and found this interesting:

```
# Attempt to enable urllib3's SNI support, if possible
try:
    from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
    pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Going deeper, the `contrib` package includes a `pyopenssl.py` script which requires:

> SSL with SNI-support for Python 2.
>
> This needs the following packages installed:
>
> - pyOpenSSL (tested with 0.13)
> - ndg-httpsclient (tested with 0.3.2)
> - pyasn1 (tested with 0.1.6)

So, to sum up:

1. Install `urllib3` and other SSL packages mentioned above, then try running that request you're doing again and see if anything has changed. My guess is that this will (at the very least) help with the `mailchimp` as it's also complaining about SSL/HTTPS issues.
2. If that doesn't work, try using `urllib3` [api](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead of `requests` to do the same task and see if that's working. If so, the problem is specifically with the packaged `urllib3` that `requests` is using, which might need some patching.

   ```
   import urllib3
   http = urllib3.PoolManager()
   r = http.request('GET', 'https://www.23andme.com/')
   ```

Sorry this isn't a definite solution, hopefully one of my suggestions will help. Update me as to the progress I'll try and help out as much as I can