# python requests on Google App Engine not working for HTTPS

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm using python-request on Google App Engine and it's not working as expected for HTTPS. Let's see an example:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://www.digitalocean.com')
```

That line works perfectly if I execute it in a terminal. Response is 200 OK (without redirects).

However, if I execute it on GAE a TooManyRedirects error is raised. 
Trying to figure out what's the problem I execute with allow_redirects=False and I can see that the response is a redirect (301) which points to the same url!!! ('location' header value is '*https://www.digitalocean.com*'). This obviously (when allow_redirect=True) happens over and over again until the TooManyRedirects error is raised.

So it seems that python-requests is not working on GAE for HTTPS  (I've tested with several URL). However HTTP works perfectly.

Any idea about what's happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also having this issue.

Comment: If it helps, I recently upgraded to urllib3==1.71 and requests==2.2.1

Comment: Filed an issue with AppEngine here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10562

Comment: I did the same in python-requests repo: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1905

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the Requests python library in Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762685/using-the-requests-python-library-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Downgrading to requests==2.1.0 worked for me.

Having an up-to-date urllib3 is important for resolving an unrelated bug (`import pwd`, as I recall).

Hopefully App Engine fixes this soon, as requests [won't](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1905).

EDIT:

I think you can also patch this in the latest requests by commenting [lines 161-175 in sessions.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1892/files#diff-28e67177469c0d36b068d68d9f6043bfR166). Untested.

Comment: How do you downgrade to an earlier version of requests?

Comment: By now this seems to be the only way to make it works.... so it's a pretty valid response while we wait for the fix in GAE. Thanks rattray! good job!

Comment: Hi @rattay. The problem only seems to be to connect to Google IP addresses (e.g., Google oAuth), as they are blocked from the sockets API, as specified here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/

For that case, your patch does not seem to work anymore. In the latest version of requests (2.8.1), commenting our sessions.SessionRedirectMixin.rebuild_auth does not resolve the error:
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: @jacob did you try downgrading to requests==2.1.0 ?

Comment: It works on 2.3 without any patches. I also posted this information on a requests git issue, and it looks like there is an official solution that is currently being worked out for the latest version 2.8+:  https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1905#issuecomment-159380704

Comment: Here to confirm that 2.1.0 nor 2.3.0 work on the latest `gcloud 104 -- app-engine-python 1.9.35`

Answer (score 5):

There is now a better solution than changing your `requests` version. As suggested in the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests#issuing_an_http_request) you can monkey patch `requests` to play nicely with Google App Engine.

First [install](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library) requests-toolbelt:

```
pip install -t lib requests-toolbelt
```

Then in your `main.py` file (or equivalent):

```
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine

requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()
```