# python-twitter, google app engine, ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter

[python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) doesn't seem to work with google app engine on the devserver because when I make a request to the twitter.api I get:

```
'Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied')).
```

However, the same code, not changing a thing, works fine when running unittests in eclipse, as well as on the live app engine server..

Does anyone know how to get python-twitter to work with the dev server?

Answer (score 0):

This is because python-twitter makes use of [the requests library](http://python-requests.org/) for which unfortunately the [core requests team](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt/pull/114#issuecomment-161214201) [do not *'seem'* to support GAE](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1905#issuecomment-34346173).

There are some known workarounds if you want to use the requests library like downgrading to an earlier requests lib version as suggested in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21610822/2295256) or having to patch some sections of the requests lib. You can have a go at it. But the fact that yours works in the live app engine server is actually a good thing.

You should follow up on this [old bug](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/issues/44) if you want official support from the python-twitter lib though.