# GCS Signed URL client ID and sample code understanding

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to implement signed URL in my code. I was trying to understand and debug the below code provided by google.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#signing-code-python

Below is what my client id from Developers console looks like

zzzzzzzzzzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.apps.googleusercontent.com

Is this the client ID which the code expects? when I give this as the keytext in the code it throws "RSA key format is not supported". Any inputs greatly appreciated, I am new to this.

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/kctang/gcs-helper) that uses GCS via signed URL. It is in Java but you might be able to derive what you need from here. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete example shows what to do basically: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python

In cloud console, API > credentials > new credentials > service account key > key type > p12. This downloads a `.p12` key

Convert key to PEM:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in /path/to/key.p12 -nodes -nocerts > /path/to/key.pem
```

Will be prompted for password: `notasecret`

> The name of the downloaded private key is the key's thumbprint. When
>   inspecting the key on your computer, or using the key in your
>   application, you need to provide the password `notasecret`. Note that
>   while the password for all Google-issued private keys is the same
>   (`notasecret`), **each key is cryptographically unique**.

Write RSA key:

```
openssl rsa -in /path/to/key.pem -inform PEM -out /path/to/key.der -outform DER
```

It's your `key.der` you'll want to supply as your key

```
with open('key.der', 'rb') as k:
    key = k.read()
```

then

```
import Crypto.PublicKey.RSA as RSA
...
...
private_key = RSA.importKey(key)
```

Comment: Hi Jeffery, The code works separately but once I integrated to Appengine code I get the below error in development environment  File ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd and on production environment I get  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~coolsigngcs/1.389989971734770545/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied')). Any inputs are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this answer addresses your main question. About the `ConnectionError`, I think it belongs in a separate question with its own answer to help future users in case they run in to similar issues. Although some might argue it's similar to the very recent http://stackoverflow.com/a/34714347/2295256 . Also note too that the linked example wasn't meant as a standalone GAE app. Glad you found a fix though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python#google-cloud-storage) for Google Cloud Storage, which among other things provides an easy way for [signing a URL](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/storage-blobs.html#gcloud.storage.blob.Blob.generate_signed_url).

Comment: I tried Jefffery's answer, the sample code in-https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python works as standalone code but changed into a appengine code, it throws errors.

Comment: That's because Appengine doesn't support requests library, after spending some time I found using urllib library instead of requests solves this issue. Here is the code- Use this -return '%s?%s'%(base_url, urllib.urlencode(query_params)) instead of return self.session.get(base_url, params = query_params). Its frustrating to see google using what it doesn't support in its sample example.